# New tag: first-layer

Tags: discussion, tags

Several questions are related to first layer calibration or issues: I found 43 of them with "first layer" in the title alone, 150 with "first layer" anywhere (no duplicates).

I propose adding a "first-layer" tag to more easily retrieve said questions.

I already applied it to my latest question without thinking about it, but I can remove it if desired.

Comment: I think it is closely related to build plate adhesion, but a first layer tag might be a good idea. Need to think it over.

Comment: Is there some problem that the first layer can have that others can't - other than bed adhesion?

Comment: A problem I see is that many issues (like bed not level, or zero position off) are usually noticed on the first layer, but they're overall setup problems, not first layer problems.

Comment: @Davo when the question is asked, it's not yet know which is the cause. But I see that the tag is not so needed as I thought.

Comment: @FarO I'm not against the tag, I'm just trying to understand the category of problems for which this would be better than some other tag (like [tag:adhesion] or [tag:bed-leveling]. If such cases exist, then I'm all for this new tag.

Comment: @0scar if Trish cannot, can you delete the tag I created? I have no rights for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [adhesion](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adhesion) tag should be used instead.

Comment: Can you delete the tag "first-layer"? I have no rights for that. The question which had that tag were in fact all about bed leveling or adhesion, I edited them (but in fact they already had the correct tags).

Comment: @FarO not a single one with [tag:first-layer] exists. The tag will die itself in a couple days.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I support this idea. A [first-layer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-layer) tag would be useful.